# Why does Eclipse complain about "Feature envy" smell in my code?

Tags: ruby, reek, feature-envy

Eclipse (RedRails) complain about "[Feature envy](http://reek.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Reek/Smells/FeatureEnvy.html)" in the following code:

```
if input_text =~ /^(---\s*\n.*?\n?)(---.*?)/m
  content_text = input_text[($1.size + $2.size)..-1] # warning in $1

  header = YAML.load($1)

  @content = content_text.strip()
  @title = header["title"]
end
```

My understanding is that I safe to ignore this warning. But I am wandering why this warning is generated. I cannot understand how I can extract method for `$1.size` and `$1`.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the surrounding code? I had a go at feeding this into reek but couldn't get it to complain about Feature Envy - Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the whole method, and the full text of reek's warning message? I can't get this to report FeatureEnvy with the current version of reek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reek is telling you that, because you are adding two properties of the same class, the calculation should actually belong in `String`. When adding string lengths this is nonsense of course, but in your case the code *can* be simplified by using `$&` (the complete matched string):

```
input_text[$&.size..-1]
```

Comment: Not strictly true. Firstly, Reek doesn't report FeatureEnvy for the code as shown above. And secondly, $1 and $2 are different objects, so Reek won't suggest that this code could be moved onto either.